# Printing a link python

Tags: python, hyperlink

I am trying to move a folder to another folder. Problem is, when I print the folders name, it also takes into account a couple of spaces within the link, thus breaking up the hyperlink.

So --

```
folder = "https://somesite/foo/bar/foo bar/foo-bar foo/bar
```

How do I print `folder` without it breaking up the hyperlink?

Comment: what is the correct output?

Answer (score 1):

I'd go this way:

```
import urllib.parse
s = urllib.parse.quote('somesite/foo/bar/foo bar/foo-bar foo/bar')
print('https://'+s)
```

outputs:

```
https://somesite/foo/bar/foo%20bar/foo-bar%20foo/bar
```

Tested with Python3

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `urllib`:

```
import urllib
urllib.quote_plus(folder) // Python 2
urllib.parse.quote_plus(folder) // Python 3
```

PS. As sindhu noticed, you need to leave `http://` unencoded.

Comment: A string is not a valid input for `urllib.urlencode(folder)`

Comment: `quote_plus` still wouldn't help OP. The whole string gets encoded like this
    'https%3A%2F%2Fsomesite%2Ffoo%2Fbar%2Ffoo+bar%2Ffoo-bar+foo%2Fbar' whereas OP only wants the query params encoded

Comment: but he adds `http://` manually (as he says it's a folder)... so I don't see a problem... still an answer... added annotation tho'.